# How do I find a common element between two arrays in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

If I have two arrays of strings in JavaScript, how do I extract the strings that both arrays have in common? For example, if I have one array `['Apple','Orange','Grape']` and another array `['Apple']`, how do I get the result `Apple`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simplest code for array intersection in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885557/simplest-code-for-array-intersection-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a data structure problem.
You can simply create an object for Array1, and then search for the keys in Object which are in Array2.

Array1 = ['Apple','Orange','Grape'];

Array2 = ['Apple','Lemon','Mango','Grape'];

```
array1 = ['Apple','Orange','Grape'];

array2 = ['Apple','Lemon','Mango','Grape'];

let obj = {};

for (let fruit of array1) {
    obj[fruit] = 1;
}

let commonArray = [];

array2.forEach(fruit => {
    if (obj[fruit] === 1) {
        commonArray.push(fruit);
    }
})
```

common array will contain Apple and Grape;